# Bootstrap Nav not toggling; .php files in seperate folders

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap to create a responsive website & am having problems with my navbar-toggle button when the screen size is small...

The button was working fine when all my .php files were in the same directory (the root); however I just changed it so that all the .php files are now in their own respective folders, (contact.php is now contact/index.php etc) to create cleaner urls. This has caused the toggle-button to no longer toggle when clicked.

My nav code is below; any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container inner-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src="../img/index/skytek-logo/Skytek_c1_S.png" width="160px" height="90px" alt="Skytek Logo"></a><p class="navbar-slogan">Dedicated to excellence in innovation and service</p>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <?php
                  /* list items with a class of "active" indicate the current section;
                   * the $section variable is set in each individual file
                   */
                 ?>
                 <li class="home <?php if ($section == "home") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">Home</a></li>
                 <li class="about <?php if ($section == "about") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>about/">About Us</a></li>
                 <li class="support <?php if ($section == "support") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>services/">Support &amp; Services</a></li>
                 <li class="sales <?php if ($section == "sales") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="#" style="color: #AAA;">Sales</a></li>
                 <li class="news <?php if ($section == "news") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="#" style="color: #AAA;">News</a></li>
                 <li class="contact <?php if ($section == "contact") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>contact/">Contact</a></li>
                 <li class="careers <?php if ($section == "careers") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>careers/">Careers</a></li>
                 <li class="staff <?php if ($section == "staff") { echo "active"; } ?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>staff/">Staff Zone</a></li>
              </ul>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->
```

Comment: As Bootstraps navbar collapsing behaviour is dependent on jQuery and Bootstraps javascript use for example the DevTools in Chrome to see if they're properly loaded. Perhaps moving the php files to another directory broke the references to these files.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ckuijjer; I changed the path of my js file from 'js/bootstrap.min.js' to '../js/bootstrap.min.js' and the toggle button now works perfectly..